# Using two passports on single itinerary

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, airlines, dual-nationality

I am an Indian passport holder travelling from the US to Rwanda and then to Israel, flying on the same (multi-city) itinerary. I have a second Indian passport that holds my Israeli visa. However, my US visa is in my first passport and I intend to use this passport to enter and exit Rwanda.
The itinerary has been booked using the first passport number. I am concerned about the airline accepting not accepting two different passport numbers for a single itinerary.  Would I be prevented from boarding the flight from Rwanda because my passport (with the Israeli visa) does not match the one on the itinerary?

Comment: Why do you have two Indian passports ? Is one expired ? Do both have the same name on it ? Visas in expired passports are still valid, so typically it's not a problem travelling with and old and a new passport as long as they are in the same name.

Comment: I have two passports (both are valid) because India issues a special passport specially for travel to Israel to ease difficulties for citizens that need to travel both to Israel and some Arab countries.
They both have the same name on it. The issue is that I want to use P1 for all other countries and P2 only for Israel. P2 has my Israel visa on it and P1 is on the itinerary.

Comment: I don’t think the passport you booked with matters as much as the passport you use when checking in https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59336/late-submission-of-api-data-whats-going-to-happen

Comment: I've never had two valid passports for the same country, but I have dual nationality and I routinely use different passports for different parts of the same booking.  No agent of any airline or government has ever even commented on this, much less caused a problem because of it.

Comment: @Hilmar Some countries btw just allow having multiple passports. For example my wife has two passport from the same country simply because we are travelling long term and the potential impact of a passport getting stolen (or lost I guess) whilst in a foreign country was big enough that we figured a spare would be worth it. (Sadly 'my country' only gives second passports if you can show you needed it in the past)

Comment: The airline check for your passport is more to cover themselves, so you can't have any possible way to blame them when it was expired, invalid, non-existent... I don't think there's actually much checking between the immigration bureau of some country and the airline. When you are in customs, you'll physically have both passports with you, and that's what they will care about when deciding to let you in. If they wouldn't want one, they'll simply ask for the other.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Speaking as a former holder of multiple passports from the same country (for the same reason as you), **you'll be fine**.

Use the same passport for entering and leaving each country and show the passport for your next destination with visas etc as needed, and you'll rarely if ever even need to show both passports.  But if you do, it's fine, airlines are quite used to people having multiple passports.

Answer (score 4):

As lambshaanxy said above, it was (mostly) fine. The airline had no issue with the two passports in Rwanda, but upon arrival in Tel Aviv, I was referred to secondary screening. The officer indicated that one of the reasons for being sent there was the lack of travel history on my passport and asked to see the other passport. It was a very friendly conversation, however, and I only had to wait around 20 minutes.